# Unlock encrypted Ubuntu via USB

Tags: ubuntu, luks

I install Ubuntu and checked the option to encrypt my disk with luks at the first install. Every time when I start my computer I get prompt to enter the password to unlock the disk. That's fine, but is there any option to do this using a USB stick instead of typing the password at every boot. Thanks in advance. Ubuntu version 16.04

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/90911/680673

Comment: https://possiblelossofprecision.net/?p=300

Comment: Please do some research before asking!

Comment: I did some research before asking.